# Just-replaced battery does not seem to be able to charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

My unibody MacBook from mid-2010 turned off a few days ago because it had low battery. This seemed strange because I had had it charging overnight, as usual. I took it to a store specialised in Apple products, and they told me that the problem seemed to be the battery. (They run, apparently, some kind of test: they took my laptop to a room where clients are not allowed). They offered to change it for a price that seemed out of proportion for this laptop (the laptop itself is probably not worth more than 150€ anywhere, and changing a battery requires removing and putting back like 12 screws). I bought a new, compatible battery and changed it myself. The laptop turned on with the new battery showing 56% charge. I started using it to drain the battery (this is what calibration tutorials recommend) but I realised that, upon plugging the charger, the battery remains constant and does not go up. The MacBook itself says that the battery is not charging, even when plugged in. Does this mean the problem was in my charger the whole time? Should I get a new charger, or is this typical of laptops whose batteries have not been calibrated yet?

Thanks.

PS.: I know it's an old laptop, they made sure I knew that in the store. It works well though, and it is enough. I can't afford to buy a new one and it's my main computer, which is why I am kind of stressed over the possibility of losing it.

Comment: Did you try an SMC reset? See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-battery-wont-charge-mh29198/mac

Comment: I followed the instructions for my specific MacBook and it does not seem to work. The problem persists. I will try to run some Linux distro from a USB drive to see if it's  a software thing, but I don't think it is.